# Pundit gem. Is there way to show record's specific attribute values over yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

i'am playing with [pundit gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). i need to show post's `title` in a flash message

```
#config/locales/pundit.en.yml

en:
  pundit:
    default: 'You cannot perform this action.'
    post_policy:
      share?: 'You cannot share post %{post.title}!'
```

controller:

```
#posts_controller.rb

def share
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
  @post.share
  redirect_to @post
end
```

all i receive is the exact the same string without any errors and substitutions

```
You cannot share post %{post.title}!
```

any suggestions? thanks

Comment: What does your controller code look like?

Comment: Hi, @Jordan, i've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I18n module has no way of knowing that `post.title` refers to `@post.title`. Rails does some of that kind of magic with its form helpers, but that magic does not extend to Pundit.

Here's how the Pundit docs [suggest customizing your error messages](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#creating-custom-error-messages):

> #### Creating custom error messages
>
> `NotAuthorizedError`s provide information on what query (e.g.
>   `:create?`), what record (e.g. an instance of `Post`), and what policy
>   (e.g. an instance of `PostPolicy`) caused the error to be raised.
>
> One way to use these `query`, `record`, and `policy` properties is to
>   connect them with `I18n` to generate error messages. Here's how you
>   might go about doing that.
>
> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
>
>   private
>
>   def user_not_authorized(exception)
>     policy_name = exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore
>
>     flash[:error] = t "#{policy_name}.#{exception.query}", scope: "pundit", default: :default
>     redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> ```yaml
> en:
>  pundit:
>    default: 'You cannot perform this action.'
>    post_policy:
>      update?: 'You cannot edit this post!'
>      create?: 'You cannot create posts!'
> ```
>
> Of course, this is just an example. Pundit is agnostic as to how you implement your error messaging.

From that information we could extrapolate something like the following:

```
private
def user_not_authorized(exception)
  policy_name = exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore
  interpolations = exception.query == 'share?' ? { title: @post.title } : {}

  flash[:error] = t "#{policy_name}.#{exception.query}", scope: "pundit", default: :default, **interpolations
  redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
end
```

And then, in your locales:

```yaml
en:
  pundit:
    default: You cannot perform this action.
    post_policy:
      share?: You cannot share post %{title}!
```

I don't have an app with Pundit in front of me so I can't test this; it's likely you'll need to finesse it a bit.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that single(') quotes don't allow string interpolation only double(") quotes

Taken from [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

> Double-quoted strings(...) can substitute the value of any Ruby expression into a string using the sequence #{ expr }. If the expression is just a global variable, a class variable, or an instance variable, you can omit the braces.

Comment: The code shown is YAML, not Ruby. You've misunderstood how the I18n module does interpolation—it uses [`sprintf`-style placeholders](https://repl.it/GUhj/1).